# Postgres ERROR: database “test” is being accessed by other users

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, ubuntu

Getting the following error when trying to drop a PostgreSQL DB say "test"

```
postgres=# DROP DATABASE test;
ERROR:  database "test" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use pg_terminate_backend to kill open connections with a query:

PostgresVersion >=9.2

```
SELECT 
   pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE
   pg_stat_activity.datname = 'test'
AND pid <> pg_backend_pid()
```

PostgresVersion <9.2

```
SELECT 
   pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.procpid)
FROM 
   pg_stat_activity
WHERE 
   pg_stat_activity.datname = 'test'
AND procpid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

where 'test' is your databasename

For PostgreSQL Version >= 13

One can use:

```
DROP DATABASE mydb WITH (FORCE);
```

Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropdatabase.html

Answer (score -1):

1) Run the following command and findout the pid 
postgres=# select * from pg_stat_activity where datname='test';

datid | datname | **pid** | usesysid | usename | current_query | waiting | xact_start | query_start | backend_start | client_addr | client_port
-------+---------+---------+----------+----------+---------------+---------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------+-------------
28091 | test | **8481** | 10 | postgres | | f | | 2008-11-12 09:12:50.277096+00 | 2008-11-12 09:11:10.328231+00 | 127.0.0.1 | 43152

2) kill -9 8481 (Here the pid is 8481)

3) Now run

postgres=# drop database test;

DROP DATABASE

Comment: this is a really bad answer: it will very likely cause data loss or even corruption to unrelated databases on your node. You should *never* "kill -9" any DB process unless you know exactly what you are doing. As pointed out by @FatFreddy, there are postgres-specific ways of achieving this without breaking any safety guarantees.

Comment: @LeoAntunes What `pg_terminate_backend` actually [does](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-admin.html) is `kill -15 8481` so this answer isn't that much wrong (it does the same, just in a more peremptory manner), but it is more explicit about what goes on under the hood.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins no. There's a world of difference between `kill -15` and `kill -9`, starting with the fact that one can be caught (and even ignored) while the other cannot. My comment stands: suggesting SIGKILL in the context of DBs is reckless at best.

Comment: @LeoAntunes I absolutely agree on this particular point. SIGKILL is definitely evil when applied to an process with a db connection.